# Grease monkey/ Tampermonkey Turning text into a link via selecting an Selector

Tags: java, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm once again asking simple questions, please forgive my level of knowledge. Thanks for reading the question.

I'm trying to create a link from the data within a `td:nth-child(4)`, its the location within a table.

The data within the table looks something like `example.com`

I want to create a ahref, so I can click this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could select every `td:nth-child(4)` using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then for each `td` change its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property so as to transform it into an anchor element :

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(4)");
for(td of tds){
  td.innerHTML = "<a href='" + td.innerText + "'>" + td.innerText + "</a>";
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>url</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>foo.bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>bar.foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```